# GDB: breakpoint in inferior process

Tags: gdb

I have a network software that I need to debug. It forks at multiple places and I need to debug one particular function handling one particular request.

Is there any way to setup a global breakpoint that would be caught even when it is in an inferior process?

I cannot use `follow-fork-mode child` because this will follow the first request, not the one I need to debug.

Comment: If you can rebuild the program, then insert the breakpoint in the program itself. On WIndows, use DebugBreak();. On Linux, raise(SIGTRAP); might work. This depends on just-in-time debugging being enabled on your system - otherwise the process will crash if it isn't being debugged.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to have gdb remain attached to all the processes.  Then you would set your breakpoint and run the program as usual; the breakpoint would fire in any sub-process that happened to hit that location.  You can use breakpoint conditions to try to reduce the number of hits.

To put gdb into multi-inferior mode, I use this:

```
set detach-on-fork off
set non-stop on
set pagination off
```

Depending on your version of gdb, you might also need `set target-async on`.

This mode can be a bit peculiar to work in.  For example, when one thread stops, the other keep going.  Also, breakpoint stops are reported, but not always obvious; and I think gdb doesn't immediately switch to the stopping thread (this may have changed in gdb git, I forget).

Comment: im doing exactly what you said, but im getting

`Cannot insert breakpoint 1.` `Cannot access memory at address 0x6ede`.

any idea on wat may be happening?

Comment: This answer helped me a great deal to debug multiple layers of Python scripts that call into my library. Thanks!